# iframe not showing up in firefox only

Tags: html, css, iframe

the iframe that i have below is not showing up. In fact it is greyed out in firebug.

But it loads perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thx alot.

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
src="http://widget.yourchalkboard.com/show_widget.php
?token=AP6sWcLms0DkU0gd7zCykmNNkUdb76uP7FPuIGlZ8aXFWlhOp8&type=leaderboard"
style="height:90px;width:728px;padding:0px;border-width:0px"></iframe>
```

Comment: [Works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/WDTY8/) on Firefox 4 for me...

Comment: It doesn't work for me in firefox 4. The `body` of iframe is empty.

Comment: yup, in chrome it works perfectly tho. anyone has any idea why?

Comment: The `iframe` is not the problem but the url, if you paste it in your browser alone, it doesn't work also.

Comment: yup, but it works in chrome. when you load that url, another iframe gets loaded.

`<iframe class=" beqfdiqindyekztyacpk" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height:90px;width:728px;padding:0px;" src="http://widget.yourchalkboard.com/widget.728x90.php?dev_token=AP6sWcLms0DkU0gd7zCykmNNkUdb76uP7FPuIGlZ8aXFWlhOp8" allowtransparency="true">`
this is loaded in chrome but not ff4. plus, in ff4, it inserts a class into the iframe too

Comment: Anoher cause of failure could be mixed content (iframe in http, website in https)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your **adblock**. just FYI. had the same problem. lost a day. lol.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Iframes, only for IE8 and below. Use object

Do this (This example will use iframes for ie9, no biggie (u can use lte ie8 instead).

```
<!--[if IE]>        
<iframe class="whatever_IE" align="???" src="????" width="???" height="???" border="none" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object  type="text/html" class="whatever" data="????" width="???" height="???"></object>   
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same thing, and it seems that the issue was that the main page's URL was accessed with an IP address instead of a domain name. More info at http://code007.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/iframe-not-loading-in-firefox-13/

Answer (score -1):

I had this type of problem once with a file in development that had the word "frame" as part of its filename.  By changing the name of the file, this problem went away.