# iframe not loading in firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe, cross-browser

Contents of iframe works well in chrome but not in firefox. I've disabled add-ons but my iframe is still empty.Both my site and iframe are https.

Below is the code:

```html
  <p><iframe class="display:inline-block;" frameborder="0" height="2622px" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emolument.com/start" width="100%"></iframe></p>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150725/iframe-not-showing-up-in-firefox-only,

Comment: can't see your code

Comment: try to give any internal path as src(on the same folder) and check whether it displays or not. in my case, above code displayed.

Comment: it's working on my firefox 59.0.2 (64 bit) on Mac

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jj49j3  it is showing on my firefox. also you are defined class and giving css value in class. it is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`<p><iframe style="display:inline-block; height: 2622px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emolument.com/start" width="100%"></iframe></p>`

Corrected style attribute and declared height as css instead of height attribute.

The height attribute btw should not have 'px'.

Comment: No, this also is not working. Showing white box only.

Comment: Can you access https://www.emolument.com/start from the address bar? Firefox has recently blocked some https certs.

Comment: Yes I can access directly from Firefox, issue is only when calling as iframe

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party plugins? Maybe an add blocker?

Comment: The width attribute on an iframe should not have '%', the unit of this attribute is px

Answer (score 1):

Check that your page housing the iframe is in the same domain as the iframe source.  If both are HTTPS, and on different domains, you may have to deal with the same-origin policy.

This is a security feature in most modern browsers that require pages and iframes to be from the same origin to allow scripts and such.

You might check out
[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the server redirect which was not working. I was working locally and the parent site was http and the iframe page was https. Once I switched the parent page to https then the iframe redirect worked in firefox.